# Relational Database Design - Create an Entity Class for Payment Type?

Tags: mysql, oracle, entity-framework, rdbms

I am currently designing a relational database for a project I am working on.

I am unsure of the best way to do it, I will try to explain as best as possible.

If I have an Entity:

```
SALE(SALE_ID, SALE_TYPE, SALE_AMOUNT, CUSTOMER_ID)
```

and,

```
PURCHASE(PURCHASE_ID, PURCHASE_TYPE, PURCHASE_AMOUNT, CUSTOMER_ID)
```

If the `PURCHASE_TYPE` and `SALE_TYPE` in each entity can only be **Cash** OR **Card**..
would if be worth creating a new Entity called for `E.g. Transaction Type` with this structure

`TRANSACTION_TYPE(TYPE_ID, PAYMENT_TYPE)`

Then replacing `PURCHASE_TYPE` and `SALE_TYPE` with `TYPE_ID` as a foreign key in the other 2 entity's?

Thanks in advance for any responses :) I hope I explained it well enough and used the correct terminology.

Comment: Since number of types is constant in nature you can use `Enum` datatype for that.

Comment: Is there a way to represent using an 'Enum' for this in the conceptual and logical design stage as this is all I am required to deliver at this point. Or should I just keep the original structure?

Comment: Fwiw, I'd have a separate table of payment types. This allows you to add payment methods in the future (e.g. PayPal) without amending your structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned the payment types are:

- Cash
- Card

So you can prefer having the datatype of `SALE_TYPE` or `PURCHASE_TYPE` AS `ENUM`.

If the number of payment types would have been larger then it would have been better to keep the types in a separate table like you said and replace the type field with the foreign key constraint.

So having `enum` data type your `SALE` table would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE `SALE` (
`SALE_ID`  int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`SALE_TYPE`  enum('Cash','Card') CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`SALE_AMOUNT`  decimal(18,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`CUSTOMER_ID`  int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`SALE_ID`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
AUTO_INCREMENT=1
ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
;
```

Same should hold for `PURCHASE` table.

Note that **`SALE_TYPE`  enum('Cash','Card') CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL ,**

In a word, I would go for keeping the original structure having the slight change in the data type of your `*_Type` field `i.e. ENUM`.